# Update check box using workflow

Tags: workflow, field-update, time-dependent-workflow

I have created a workflow and I need to update a check box based on other field

If checkbox1------>is true then need to update chekbox2 as true
If checkbox1 ------> is false then need to update chexkbox2 as false...

How can I achieve this using one workflow.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 4):

Go to Setup Menu->Create->Workflows->Process Builder->New->

NameYourProcess

Save

Add Object You wanna make this workflow work On

Mark "when a record is created or edited"

Save

Add Criteria -> Select a name for this. -> Select "No criteria Just execute the actions!" Save.

Click on Inmidiate actions->Name It-> Choose "Select the xxx record that started your process".

Name the action keep selected "No criteria—just update the records!" and search for the chekbox2 field and put "Reference" as a Type and search for the checkbox1 on the value. Save.

This should make it.

PD: I prefered using Process builder over classic workflows since it's more visual Friendly.